# SSIS ETL Unpivot transformation to T-SQL Unpivot

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis, etl, unpivot

I am trying to convert some SSIS ETL into sql Server code. Old ETl was written for 2005 and new T-SQL code is being written for 2012. I have the following data being transformed in SSIS ETL:

**Source Table:** AssetName, MoodyRating, SPRating, FitchRating

**Source Data:**

```
FirstAsset, 1 , 2 , 3
SecondAsset, 4, 5, 6
```

That is being unpivoted to the following:

**Target Table:** AssetName, RatingSouce, RatingValue

**Target Data:**

```
FirstAsset, Moody, 1
FirstAsset, SP, 2
FirstAsset, Fitch, 3
SecondAsset, Moody, 4
SecondAsset, SP, 5
SecondAsset, Fitch, 6
```

I think I can do this in SQL using the UNPIVOT command but I can not find an example that will inject the RatingSource as part of the unpivot process. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `UNPIVOT` function and then just replace the `rating` in the column names:

```
select AssetName,
  replace(RatingSouce, 'Rating', '') RatingSouce,
  RatingValue
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  RatingValue
  for RatingSouce in ([MoodyRating], [SPRating], [FitchRating])
) unpiv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/74f34/3)

Comment: Thanks for the example. It was exactly what I was looking for. In my actual case I needed to a case statement instead of replace to better represent that data I was converting but that was it.

Comment: @JookyDFW yes, you can use a `case` to do this, I just used `replace` to show how it could be done. :)